# In material ui, why isn't the "spacing" styling attribute doing anything when I try and space elements in my Box?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, spacing, box

I'm using materialUI in my React 16.10 application.  I have two buttons in a Box.

```
        <Box
          style={{
            marginTop: "3rem",
            marginLeft: "1rem",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
    spacing: 1,
          }}
        >
          <Button onClick={handleSave} variant="contained" color="primary">
            SAVE
          </Button>

          <Button
            onClick={toDetailsView}
            startIcon={<CancelIcon />}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
          >
          CANCEL
          </Button>
        </Box>
```

Even though I'm using "spacing: 1", the buttons appear right next to each other so it is impossible to distinguish where one ends and the next begins ...

[image]

How do I add style so that there is a little bit of space in between the buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for easy fix ? 
margin: 1rem;

Comment: I already had 'marginLeft: "1rem",' in my style.  Changing "marginLeft" to just "margin" still results in the same problem.

Comment: Well you are applying styles to the the “Box” component not to the buttons. Set className to first button and try marginLeft once again

Comment: You set margin for Box component only as I can see so whatever is next to the box it will push it 10px=1rem to the left

Comment: Please let me know about any outcome and upvote if this was helpful to you Dave

Comment: Can you spell it out for me?  You're saying applying the margin to the Box element or the Button elements?

Comment: So I said. That you applied margins to the Box component not the button it self. So inside the Box component there are two buttons. Please apply the margins on the first button as margin right or second button as margin left.